# SWTableViewCell left utility buttons, visible on first load in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

On iPad if I run my app is shows this as the view is loaded:
[image]

In my `PatientAppointmentTableViewCell` which is a subclass of `SWTableViewCell`.
In the `.m` file of this class I've added this method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = self.contentView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = [self leftUtilityButtonsWidth];
    self.frame = frame;

    self.cellScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) + [self utilityButtonsPadding], CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));

    if (!self.cellScrollView.isTracking && !self.cellScrollView.isDecelerating)
    {
        self.cellScrollView.contentOffset = [self contentOffsetForCellState:_cellState];
        [self updateCellState];
    }
}
```

To which in every line I'm getting error

> No Visible @interface for 'PatientAppointmentTableViewCell' declares
>   the selector leftUtilityButtonsWidth
>   
> property cellScrollView not found on object of type PatientAppointmentTableViewCell

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure its not the  default feature for iPad?

Comment: @Mr.UB I don't know... is it? Well it should not just automatically reveal the left button like that.

Answer (score 0):

This bug in the default code and raised on the Github repo also.
See the comment on https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell/issues/353

This is the fix, I have used and it is working fine.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{    
    BOOL isPad = [UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
    if (isPad == YES) {
        layoutUpdating = YES;
        [super layoutSubviews];
        layoutUpdating = NO;
    } else {
        [super layoutSubviews];
    }

    // Offset the contentView origin so that it appears correctly w/rt the enclosing scroll view (to which we moved it).
    CGRect frame = self.contentView.frame;
```